# How to install Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk into the dotnet sdk folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild, dotnet-sdk

I know this is going to sound like a silly question but I am trying to build a solution that requires Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk 6.0.0 to be installed inside "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk\Sdk".
I can see "other" sdks in the "Sdks" folder but just not the "arcade" sdk.

I can't seem to find any documentation here https://github.com/dotnet/arcade on how to install this SDK onto my computer.
I did download the solution and was able to build the solution but that did not install it nor did it build an installer.

Comment: Arcade is a tool for people developing .NET itself. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @omajid I am trying to edit EntityFramework 6 source code to support DateTime instead of DateTime2 in SQL 2019.  Back in 2018 I was able to make the edit to the source code and build. Now I just want to edit the newer version and build. https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/578

Answer (score 1):

It is a dotnet package under the github nuget source `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-eng/nuget/v3/index.json`.

You should restore the project from the package source for your own project.

See [this official link](https://github.com/dotnet/arcade#getting-started).

So please try to add it under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Sources**:

To be safe, add these four nuget sources:

```
 <packageSources>  
    <add key="dotnet-public" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-public/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="dotnet-tools" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-tools/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="dotnet-eng" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-eng/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="vs-buildservices" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/azure-public/vside/_packaging/vs-buildservices/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
```

[image]

**Then**, open your own project and then rebuild your project to test whether it could solve your issue.

Comment: Perry Qian-MSFT, I already have the dotnet package, both the pkg file and the VS package source. I even have enabled "Use previews of the .NET Core SDK" enabled in VS options. None of those install it into "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk\Sdk" which is where the VS is wanting it to be when I try to build the project.  When I try to build the project it throws an error saying it can't find the location listed above.  So something must install it to that location? Just not show how to install it in that location.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. And I also face the same behavior as you described. And I cannnot install that package. And use `dotnet tool install` with that package and also fail on it. Maybe you should [contact with the team on github](https://github.com/dotnet/arcade/issues). And you can share the link here to let more community members join in it.

Comment: Make sure you check the `Include Prelease` checkbox next to the search bar in Manage Packages for Solution for it to show in the search results.