# How to integrate openiddict source code to my project?

Tags: c#, debugging, openiddict

I wanna debug openiddict and study it.But I encounter a lot of difficulties.
I appended the openiddict source code by Add->Existing Project.
Some errors occur during compilation such as
Error   CS0103  The name 'StringSyntaxAttribute' does not exist in the current context

Error   CS8370  Feature 'nullable reference types' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater.
And there is an exclamation on each Dependecies node

I try copy Directory.Packages.props to the solution folder but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

A. For your language problem, try to do this in **Project** > **Right Click** then select **Edit Project File**

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>Latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) about C# language versioning.

B. Add **OpenIddict Source Code** in your project (Not recommended)

1. Download OpenIddict source code in [here](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/releases/tag/4.4.0). Then extract **sourcecode.zip**
2. Right click **Solution** of your **Project** > **Add** > **Existing Project** > Select **OpenIddict.csproj** from **openiddict-core-4.4.0\openiddict-core-4.4.0\src\OpenIddict** folder

C. Or Install **OpenIddict** via **NuGet** (Recommended)

**VS2022** > **Tools** > **NuGet Package Manager** > **Package Manager Console** > Wait until **Package Manager Console** visible at bottom of VS2022 then typo **NuGet\Install-Package OpenIddict -Version 4.4.0** > **Enter**

Look at [here](https://github.com/openiddict) example and documentation

When you install from **NuGet**, you can get the latest updates from the developer, making it easier for you to focus on Your Project.

Comment: It prompts `The SDK 'Microsoft.Dotnet.Arcade.Sdk' specified could not be found` , when I add OpenIddict.csproj follow your method.

Comment: @MutipleQA, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65331632/how-to-install-microsoft-dotnet-arcade-sdk-into-the-dotnet-sdk-folder