# How to install Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk

Tags: .net

I want to read the source code of the openiddict-core project, but I get an error after downloading the source code and opening it.

error  : The SDK 'Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk' specified could not be found.  D:\projects\openiddict-core\Directory.Build.props

I tried the solution in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65331632) below and it didn't solve the problem.How do I fix it?